# Splitting a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to split up a single select element into multiple select elements with the separator of "/"

For an example this would be the original code.

```
<select>
<option value="1234">Type 1 / Black</option>
<option value="5678">Type 2 / White</option>
</select>
```

And for this example, i need the followin results.

```
<select>
<option value="12">Type 1</option>
<option value="56">Type 2</option>
</select>

<select>
<option value="34">Black</option>
<option value="78">White</option>
</select>
```

They have unique values, so if you look at the first one, and when you select "Type 1" and "Black you get the value of "1234"... hope this makes sense... And for an example, if option if any of the options are the same such as.

```
<select>
<option value="12">Type 1 / Black</option>
<option value="34">Type 1 / White</option>
</select>
```

I need those joint into a single option element such as

```
<select>
<option value="12">Type 1</option>
</select>

<select>
<option value="12">Black</option>
<option value="34">White</option>
</select>
```

Have you done this before, or any ideas on best practise on this one ?. Appreciate any help on this guys!. Really do!.

Comment: `.cloneNode(true)` the select element, then walk through the `option` elements for both the original and the clone, and `.split("/")` and set the `.text` and `.value` of each `option`.

Comment: You have one select element on an HTML page and want to turn that into two via some JS?

Comment: Now you're adding more requirements. How about showing what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Exactly, i just edited below "And for an example, if any of the options are the same such as" I find this a little complicated in my head and really need any suggestions on this if any...

Comment: Yes, sorry "cookie monster" i've just realised that, so far i've not tried much as i'm not actually sure on where to begin and what would be the best practise for this, it feels very bloated in my head and i really don't wan't bloated code and that's why i'm posting this here.

Comment: Are you sure about the values in last code area. What is the rule, how you assign the value 2 to both of second select?

Comment: I've just edited the above example, i'm still trying to figure out the best practise. Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

[here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLwsn/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tLwsn/1/)

```
          <select class='main-select'>
            <option value="1">Type 1 / Black</option>
            <option value="2">Type 1 / Yellow</option>
            <option value="3">Type 2 / White</option>
            <option value="4">Type 3 / Blue</option>
          </select>
```

And the `JS`

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
       var firstSelectItems=[],
           secondSelectItems=[],
           mainSelect=$('.main-select');

           mainSelect.find('option').each(function(index,item){
               var currentVal=item.text,
                   realCurrentValue=item.value,
                   splits=currentVal.split('/'),
                   former=splits[0],
                   last=splits[1];                                 
  addItem('<option value="'+realCurrentValue+'">'+former+'</option>',firstSelectItems);
   addItem('<option value="'+realCurrentValue+'">'+last+'</option>',secondSelectItems);
           });
          //mainSelect.remove();
          $('<select/>',{html:firstSelectItems.join('')}).insertAfter(mainSelect);
          $('<select/>',{html:secondSelectItems.join('')}).insertAfter(mainSelect);

      function addItem(_val, _array){
          for(var i=0;i< _array.length; i++){
          if( _array[i]==_val) return;
        }
        _array.push(_val);
      }
   });
```

Comment: there is a high chance that the OP can have some original option like `Type1 / Black / Big` or even more `Type1 / Black / Big / Sold` ... This seems to work only for the case in which the option has only 1 separator `/`.

Comment: as a matter of fact, He didn't mention that in his question @KingKing

Comment: that's why I said **there is a high chance**, otherwise the comment would be different, and of course this answer was totally useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
            $(document).on('ready',function () {
                var categories = [];
                var categorySelect = $('<select class="category_select"></select>');
                var productSelect = $('<select class="product_select"></select>');
                var splitElement = $('.split_select option');

                $.each(splitElement, function(i) {
                    var elem = $(this);
                    var tempValue = elem.attr('value');
                    var catProduct = elem.text().split(' / ');
                    var tempCat = catProduct[0];
                    var tempProduct = catProduct[1];
                    if ( $.inArray(tempCat, categories)==-1 ) {
                        categories.push( tempCat );
                        categorySelect.append('<option value="' + tempValue + '">' + tempCat + '</option>');
                    };
                    productSelect.append('<option value="' + tempValue + '">' + tempProduct + '</option>');
                });

                $('.splited')
                    .append( categorySelect )
                    .append( productSelect );
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <select class="split_select">
            <option value="1">Category 1 / Black</option>
            <option value="2">Category 2 / White</option>
            <option value="3">Category 3 / Red</option>
            <option value="4">Category 3 / Blue</option>
            <option value="5">Category 3 / Yellow</option>
        </select>

        <div class="splited"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

I see you made mess with examples above, but on this base you can do whatever you want.